# function not working properly when run on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 2 fields: date field `#datefromtoday` and number of days `#daysfromtoday`. I use a javascript function to:

1) Automatically listen to the datefromtoday and (if there is a date) display the number of days from today when the page is loaded

2) adjust the date from today when entering/modify the number of days.

Here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

 function modifyDays(){ //definy function to modify days
    var endDateToDays = $( "#datefromtoday" ).val();
    var endDateToDays_obj = new Date(endDateToDays); // convert in object
    var endDateToDays_ms = endDateToDays_obj.getTime(); // convert in ms

    var todayDate = new Date(); //
    var todayDate_ms = todayDate.getTime(); //

    var daysFromToday =  parseInt(Math.ceil( (endDateToDays_ms - todayDate_ms) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ) ) || ''; //if not number display nothing


    document.getElementById("daysfromtoday").value = daysFromToday; //outuput
 }



    modifyDays(); //here is the problem. If I delete this line of code, everything works perfectly


    $("#datefromtoday").on('change', function(){ //run function when modify delay date
        modifyDays();       
    });
 });
```

**PROBLEM**

the modifyDays function works like a charm on the on.change event, but
when is loaded on document ready, it interferes with datatables www.datatables.net and also with other scripts, and they don't work anymore...

I'm probably using the wrong code to call the function on page load.... any ideas? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: move your function out size of $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @HoangHieu What would that do? The issue is with where the function is called, not where it's defined.

Comment: @Dave Newton  I think when the code call modifyDays(), javascript hasn't ready for it... :) if move function out of ready, I think it will be fine

Comment: @HoangHieu  That's precisely the point of calling it in `$(function() { ... })`. It's more likely the code *inside* `modifyDays` is getting bogus values and failing. Again: moving the *function definition* outside of jQ's DOMready won't have *any* impact if it's still *called* in DOMready.

Comment: modifyDays function has no reference to www.datatables.net. How can it interfere with datatables.net. Please check where & how you are adding script tag to html/jsp file

Comment: If ur modifying something  in a datatable in `ready` you should make sure ur datatable has loaded first. Datatables redraws the attached table, which will mess with/break any event handlers because the element they are targetting gets redrawn and thus stripped of its events. Impossible to be any more specific since u have no datatables code in ur post

Comment: The only thing I see that would throw an exception and break other scripts is if `document.getElementById("daysfromtoday")` were null.  Try replacing that line with `$("#daysfromtoday").val(daysFromToday);`

Comment: For troubleshooting, add an alert to give you the values of endDateToDays_ms, todayDate_ms, and daysFromToday as soon as you calculate them so you can see how far the function gets and what values it comes up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is because of calling the main function, in the body element of the html page, add an onload attribute:

```
<body onload="loaded()">
```

and declare loaded as that main function:

```
var loaded = function (){

   function modifyDays(){ //definy function to modify days
       var endDateToDays = $( "#datefromtoday" ).val();
       var endDateToDays_obj = new Date(endDateToDays); // convert in object
       var endDateToDays_ms = endDateToDays_obj.getTime(); // convert in ms

       var todayDate = new Date(); //
       var todayDate_ms = todayDate.getTime(); //

       var daysFromToday =  parseInt(Math.ceil( (endDateToDays_ms - todayDate_ms) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ) ) || ''; //if not number display nothing


       document.getElementById("daysfromtoday").value = daysFromToday; //outuput
   }



   modifyDays(); //here is the problem. If I delete this line of code, everything works perfectly


   $("#datefromtoday").on('change', function(){ //run function when modify delay date
       modifyDays();       
   });
};
```

Then it should work if the problem is how the function is called.

Comment: In past experience, I have had problems with jQ's "ready" handler but when I changed it to this format, it worked.

Comment: I suppose it's *possible*, but I find it unlikely. `ready` already attaches its handler to `onload`, e.g., https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js.

Comment: Inline HTML event handlers should be avoided whenever possible (which is always) because they create spaghetti code and cause global function wrappers to be generated for the value of the inline event handler to execute in. They also cause any references to this to point to window, rather than the DOM element.  There just isn't any good reason to be using them.

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually ready attaches itself to DOMContentLoaded, which fires before load.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Actually, it does both, as referenced in the source I linked to, and relies on removing the `load` handler after DOMContentLoaded. In either case, my point to Gregory Ling still stands--the handler is attached to `load`, but may be removed before it fires.

Comment: @Gregory it works!!!! Thanks! Could you please spend 2 words and try to let me understand why...? I'm confused... Thanks again!

Comment: @Scott thanks for your comments. Gregory solution works... do you have an alternative to try which is not an Inline HTML event handlers?

Comment: @Dave please see the above comment. Thanks!!

Comment: @codeispoetry Same comments as before. Something is your method is blowing up. The only reason it works is precisely what Scott Marcus said. My first assumption would be a load order dependency, and your function is relying on the side effect of some other script. You're masking the problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton If you read the link that you supplied, you'll see that there is an IE 9-10 specific solution that uses readystate === complete (which fires at roughly the same time as DOMContentLoaded), then there is DOMContentLoaded (which is provided for all modern implementations) and load is used (as the comments say) as a fallback.  So, in any modern client, DOMContentLoaded is used.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Agreed. Again, my response to Gregory was that jQuery attaches to the load event, which is what his inline JS does, making this no better from the jQuery point of view. That it works masks an underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is because of you are calling the function on page load. The error might be coming from inside the function modifyDays. Only dependency I see is #datefromtoday and #daysfromtoday. Check whether those nodes are there when the function execute on dom ready event.

Answer (score 0):

If the timing of the function call is the problem, you can put the `modifyDays();` call in a `window.setTimeout(modifyDays, 5000);` or something of the sort to delay it until the other scripts finish loading, so this snippet doesn't interrupt or interfere with them. You may want to put a placeholder in the html for the seconds when it isn't loaded yet if this works.